# iPad safari mobile JavaScript files caching

Tags: ipad, caching, safari

Does iPad Safari cache JavaScript files? It seems to be no. If my Safari doesn't cache scripts, how can I make it to do that?

Comment: How do you know it's not caching scripts?

Comment: 1) it loads the second time as long as first time; 2) if I make any change in script and refresh page, it gets new version

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?  My iPad Safari is also not caching scripts or images or anything else.  The same setup caches fine in IE.  Oddly, if I load my page then click in the URL box and then hit go (reloading the current page), then the caching starts working.

Comment: The only solution for us was to create separate lightweight mobile version of site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Creating a Manifest File** ([See here for declaring a manifest file](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/Client-SideStorage/Client-SideStorage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002051-CH4-SW3))

The manifest file specifies the resources—such as HTML, JavaScript, CSS, and image files —to downloaded and store in the application cache. After the first time a webpage is loaded, the resources specified in the manifest file are obtained from the application cache, not the web server.

The manifest file has the following attributes:

- It must be served with type text/cache-manifest.
- The first line must contain the text CACHE MANIFEST.
- Subsequent lines may contain URLs for each resource to cache or
  comments.
- Comments must be on a single line and preceded by the # character.
- The URLs are file paths to resources you want to download and cache
  locally. The file paths should be relative to the location of the
  manifest file—similar to file paths used in CSS—or absolute.
- The HTML file that declares the manifest file, described in Declaring
  a Manifest File, is automatically included in the application cache.
  You do not need to add it to the manifest file.

Excerpt from:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/Client-SideStorage/Client-SideStorage.html

[More info about the HTML5 Offline Application Cache](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/Client-SideStorage/Client-SideStorage.html)